# C# issue getting 3 decimal places

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm having an issue with rounding. I divide two numbers input by the user I always get either '0' or a whole number.

```
public static void GetRatios()//This method attains the users ratio inputs
{
    double ratioCalc = waistMeasurment / heightMeasurment; //Calculates the ratio
    ratio = Math.Round((Decimal)ratioCalc, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //Round the answer to 3 decimal places 'ratio' is initialised in the class
}
```

Comment: `double ratioCalc = (double)waistMeasurment / heightMeasurment`

Comment: Ill update my post

Comment: @doctor that worked perfectly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because `waistMeasurment` and `heightMeasurment` are `int`.

Cast them to `double` and you'll get the result in `double` as well.

You just need to cast one of them to double in order to have floating point division (like @doctor wrote in the comment):

```
double ratioCalc = (double)waistMeasurment / heightMeasurment;
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, how do I do that?